# mathematical power operator not working as expected

Tags: c, math

```
short sho1, sho2;
printf("Enter two shorts.\n");
scanf("%hd %hd", &sho1, &sho2);
printf("%hd^%hd is %hd.\n", sho1, sho2, sho1^sho2);
```

When I enter '2 2', I get this output:

> 2^2 is 0.

How come? I'm using the MinGW GCC compiler in Eclipse, in case that's of any importance.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if you simply want the square of an integer, don't use pow() but x*x. This saves you some floating point conversions. It seems obvious, but sometimes people tend to forget that. Including me when I looked the first time for a power operator :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`^` is not the mathematical power operator in C, it's the [bitwise exclusive-OR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3akey979%28VS.80%29.aspx).  You probably want the [pow function](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/pow.html), which takes two doubles.

Comment: You can apply `^` to doubles, in which case the complier C truncates the values then exclusive ORs the bit patterns of the corresponding ints. When working on anti-collision algorithms for UAVs (uninhabited air vehicles), some sample code from NASA had an optimisation which never happened as it calculated squares using `dist^2`.  (gcc 4 doesn't truncate; this was a few years ago on windows )

Comment: Oooh, +1 for very interesting comment.

Answer (score 7):

You aren't using the operator that you think you're using.

`^` is the [bitwise XOR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR).

You are looking for the [pow function](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/pow.html).

> Prototype: double pow(double b, double p);
>
> Header File: math.h (C) or cmath (C++)
>
> Explanation: This function raises b to the p power.

Wikipedia has a useful [list of operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) that are valid in C and C++.

Comment: use pow function from cmath/math.h

Comment: @Amit - yes, I was looking for a better formatted reference for the pow function.  I'd forgotten about the cprogramming.com site.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` operator is not the power operator; it is the bitwise XOR operator. For the power operator you want to use the function [`pow`](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/pow.html) declared in `math.h`. Thus:

```
pow(2.0, 2.0)
```

will return `4.0` (intentionally emphasizing that parameters and return value are doubles).

Note further that `pow` returns a double so you will have to change the format specifier to `%g`:

```
printf("%hd^%hd is %g.\n", sho1, sho2, pow((double)sho1, (double)sho2));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no "power" operator in C - ^ is the XOR (bitwise exclusive OR) operator

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pow() function in C.

```
pow(base, exponent);
```

It's in the math.h header file.

Answer (score 1):

In c `^`, is the exclusive or operator.  In order to do powers, you have to use the `pow`
 function.

`pow(2,2)`