# C++ using E in a mathematical equation

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to solve aX<sup>2</sup> + bX + c = 0 but I can't seem to make it work with using the math header (which I'm not supposed to use).

```
printf("%E",(-b+(b*b-4*a*c)E0.5)/2a);
```

Comment: I must say I'm genuinely surprised and bemused to see the ideas people come up with -- of course this doesn't work, but one might very well have expected it to work. +1 for sharing this idea!

Answer (score 7):

Use `std::sqrt` from header `<cmath>`. Also, you must write `(2 * a)`, not `2a`.

Another thing: don't use the textbook formula for solving quadratic equations. Use [the method described there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503849/quadratic-equation-in-ada/4504415#4504415).

If you can't use the math header, then you have to implement the square root eg. as described [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number):

```
double my_abs(double x)
{
    return x > 0 ? x : -x;
}

double my_sqrt(double x)
{
    static const double eps = 1e-12;
    double u = x, uold;

    do { uold = u; u = (u * u + x) / (2 * u); }
    while (my_abs(u - uold) < eps * x);

    return u;
}
```

Comment: Funny thing, though - he *can't* use `<cmath>`.

Comment: *not supposed to* is different from *can't* ... smells like homework but he can roll his own loops and get an approximate of square root if he must.

Comment: You can't include anything aside from stdio.h

Comment: @user - A C++ course assignment in which the only allowed header is `<stdio.h>`? Not `<iostream>`, not even `<cstdio>`, but `<stdio.h>`? My first suggestion is that you should ask for your money back.

Answer (score 2):

That is *not at all* how `E` works.

`E` is used in floating point literals, to express a number scientific notation (more or less)

```
// x will be the same as 0.00104
double x = 1.04e-3
```

If you want to take a square root, then you should be using a `sqrt` function:

```
sqrt(-b+(b*b-4*a*c))/2 / a
```

Of course, since you can't use `#include <cmath>`, you'd have to roll your own!

Comment: Very nice idea, but how do I make such a function ? We're right back where we started

Comment: Wouldn't writing the function be your job? Lucky for you, Alexandre gave you the answer, but the idea is that you find a way to write one yourself, or at least search for one on your own. Btw, a quick google search brought me here [Wikipedia: Methods of computing square roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots), so it's not like the stuff is difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `E` as `pow` in C/C++ (see for example [mathematical power operator not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027877/c-mathematical-power-operator-not-working-as-expected/2027894#2027894)). And the `E` in the `printf` will print the number as Scientific notation, you know? (like 3.9265E+2).

Answer (score 0):

`E` only works when you're typing out a constant floating point, like `2.2E6`. To compute exponentials, you need to use `std::pow()` from `<cmath>`. In this case, you could use `std::sqrt()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose with E you mean the power, but there is no such power operator in C++. Use either the `pow` function or the, in your case more appropriate, `sqrt` function. But these are both in `<cmath>`. If you cannot use `<cmath>` (homework assignment?), you might have to implement your own square root function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing scientific notation (`3.2E6 = 3.2 x 10^6`) with exponentiation (`sqrt(5) = 5^(1/2)`), where I am using `^` for "raise to the power of". Unfortunately, c++, like C, doesn't have a built-in power operator. So you would normally use either `sqrt(x)` or `pow(x,0.5)` from the math library.

However, if you want to solve this *without* the math header, you'll have to find a different way to calculate square roots. You could write a subroutine to use the [Babylonian or Heron method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots), for example...